# Project is not working in Gradle for Apache NetBeans

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans

I am trying to run the Gradle project for Apache NetBeans but all it says is that

"In order to be able to read this project, NetBeans needs to execute its Gradle scripts as priming build. Executing Gradle scripts allows arbitrary code execution, as current user, on this system."

Also I can't seem to find the Gradle plugin for Apache NetBeans. Please help.

Comment: Which NetBeans version are you using? With any recent version (12.x, 13.x) you don't need to download a Gradle plugin explicitly. When you open a Gradle project for the first time, NetBeans will ask you if you trust that project. If you don't trust the project I think NetBeans won't run the Gradle script.

Comment: I am using Apache Netbeans 12.6. When I open the project, the first thing that is says is that there is project problems.

Comment: When you right-click on the project and choose "Properties", you can "trust" the script in the "Gradle Execution" section.